# xsl get position content and position+1 content in foreach

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/hundred">
<div class="statistics">
    <div class="statistic1">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="statistic2">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
    </div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Currently I have the `current positioned` label being outputted for `both divs`. What I need is for `the div statistics2` to output the next loops elements label.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/hundred">
<xsl:variable name="pos2" select="/*/hundreds/hundred[position=position()+1]/>
<div class="statistics">
    <div class="statistic1">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="$pos2/label != NULL">
    <div class="statistic2">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="$pos2/label"/></h2>
    </div>
    </xsl:if>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is untested and probably incorrect but as you can see this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The next `hundred` element is called the following sibling so using XPath you find it with `following-sibling::hundred[1]` and its `label` child using `following-sibling::hundred[1]/label`. Note that that is pure XPath navigation in the input tree, it is not related to `for-each`.

So with XSLT you could write

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::hundred[1]">
  <div class="statistics2"> 
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::hundred[1]/label"/></h2>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: This did not work: <h2><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::hundred[position()+1]"/></h2>

Comment: I clearly wrote `following-sibling::hundred[1]/label` and not what you put in your comment.